# activity can't receive bundle extras

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a local notification in my android app. it is located at the mainactivity. it uses a string array to fill the context text field. i also use an integer which i named notifCount that increments every time the notification executes. when that local notification shows at the top, it changes it's context text. my problem is when the i call notifCount in the onCreate on the activity that is called by the pendingIntent, it seems that it shows the activity and the onCreate on the activity is not loaded.

here's the part of my mainactivity which launches the local notif;

```
public void showNotif(){
        contentTxt = arrContentTxt[notifCount];
        Log.d("Batelec", "main notifCount: "+notifCount);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("notifCountNum", notifCount);


        Uri notifSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("MyPower Reminder")

            .setContentText(contentTxt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSound(notifSound)

            .addAction(0, "View Full Reminder", pi)
            .build();

        i.putExtras(b);

        NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifMgr.notify(0, notif);

        notifCount++;
        if(notifCount == contentTxtLength){
            notifCount = 0;
        }
    }
```

here's my the local notif receiver;

```
package com.example.mypower_build101;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotifReceiver extends Activity {

    TextView txtMsg, txtTitle;
    Bundle b;
    int notifCount;
    String[] fullTxt, fullTitle;
    String notifFullTxt, notifFullTitle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notif_receiver);

        txtMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
        txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        Resources res = getResources();
        fullTitle = res.getStringArray(R.array.notifContentText);
        //fullTxt = res.getStringArray(R.array.notifFullTxt);

        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        try{
            notifCount = b.getInt("notifCountNum");
            Log.d("Batelec", "receiver notifCount: "+notifCount);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Batelec", "notifReceiver error: "+e);
        }

        if(b != null){


            notifFullTitle = fullTitle[notifCount];
            //notifFullTxt = fullTxt[notifCount];

            Log.d("Batelec", "notifCount: "+notifCount);
            txtTitle.setText(""+notifFullTitle);
            //txtMsg.setText(""+notifFullTxt);
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Batelec", "b null");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifReceiver.class);
 i.putExtras(b); // add here
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, (int)(Math.random*100), i, 0);

            Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("MyPower Reminder")

                .setContentText(contentTxt)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setSound(notifSound)

                .addAction(0, "View Full Reminder", pi)
                .build();
     NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifMgr.notify(notifCount, notif); //instead of zero, write notifCount
```

Comment: hey, it worked somehow. the notif receiver already receives the notifCount, but it just receives 0 every time. please help

Comment: still didn't work. i've run it and it makes the 3 notifications appears at the same time

Comment: I think, its because of pending intent id.  change it to random numbers

Comment: I have updated the post with pending intent id. It may help!

Comment: oh, finally it worked now. thanks anitha. i really appreciate your help. thanks a lot

Comment: sorry for the late comment, i did just what you told me. putting the random number generator for the id param